# Retrieve id with condition

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, select

I am trying to allocate academy for student with only one click. This allocation need to have condition before allocating a specific academy to the student.

Here are my database tables:

tblAcademy

```
    Acad_id name  seat_available
   ------------------------------
    1       A        2
    2       B        2
    3       C        1
    4       D        5
    5       E        3
```

tblStudent

```
    stud_Id name   `stud_purcentage` `stud_result`   acad_id
   ----------------------------------------------------------
     1       Alex     100               `Pass`
     2       Lee      80.5              `Pass`
     3       Lea      40.3              `Fail`
     4       Loane    10                `Fail`
     5       john     50                `Pass`
```

tblAcademy_selection

```
   stud_id Acad_id order_preference
   --------------------------------
    1      1          1
    1      3          2
    4      3          1
    4      2          2
    4      4          3
```

`Acad_id` is foreign key of `tblAcademy`. The `acad_id` can remain null if the condition is not respected a student may do not have academy.

In the `tblAcademy` selection it shows that a student can select many academy but only one has to be allocate to them.

The allocation must be based on the seat available by the academy, on those who pass and allocate those from best percentage to the worst.

Till now I have been able to retrieve from the best to worst student and those who passed. I have then join those student id to the `tblAcademy_selection`.

```
SqlConnection dbcon = new SqlConnection(_conString);

SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand();
scmd.CommandText = "SELECT stud_Id, stud_fname, stud_purcentage, stud_totalMarks FROM tblStudent WHERE stud_result = 'Pass' ORDER BY stud_purcentage DESC";
scmd.Connection = dbcon;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dbcon.Open();

da.Fill(dt);

string[] array = new string[dt.Rows.Count];

// foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
for (int a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
{
    // studID = row["stud_Id"].ToString();
    array[a] = dt.Rows[a]["stud_Id"].ToString();

    SqlCommand scmd2 = new SqlCommand();
    scmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblAcademy ta JOIN tblAcademy_Selection tas ON ta.acad_Id = tas.acad_Id WHERE stud_Id IN ('" + array[a] + "')";
    scmd2.Connection = dbcon;

    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd2);
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    da2.Fill(dt2);

    string[] array2 = new string[dt2.Rows.Count];

    for (int a2 = 0; a2 < dt2.Rows.Count; a2++)
    {
        array2[a2] = dt2.Rows[a2]["stud_Id"].ToString();

        SqlCommand scmd3 = new SqlCommand();
    }
}
```

In my first SQL statement I have selected those who have best percentage and those whose who passed and stored in an array.
With the for loop I am retrieving the data table value

In the second SQL statement, I have made a join with `tblAcademy` and `tblAcademy_selection` where the `tblAcademy_selection.stud_id` is in the retrieve value that I have done in the first statement.

I am having difficulty to apply the condition in which if an student choice of academy seat is full it move to the second choice and if the second is full it move to the third and so on.

A student may not have academy if all his choice academy seat is full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply a filter condition in your SQL statement to filter out records with tblAcademy.seat_available = 0.

Then generate a row_number or rank based on order preference and retrieve records with generated row_number =1.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT tas.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY stud_id ORDER BY order_preference) AS row_id 
FROM tblAcademy ta 
JOIN tblAcademy_Selection tas ON ta.acad_Id = tas.acad_Id 
WHERE ta.seat_available >0 and stud_Id IN ('" + array[a] + "')"
) DTL 
WHERE row_id = 1
```

Comment: Thx for answering me. I am getting syntax error in for the DTL, what is the DTL use for please?

Comment: Its ok for dtl,I manage to make correct,can you explain the sql in more detail please, because I am getting the first choice selection of the student

Comment: DTL is just an alias name for the subquery. Issue should be in this one i think. stud_Id IN ('" + array[a] + "'). Remove the " at the end and try again.

Comment: To explain the query - I just added a filter condition and a dense_rank function to your existing query. I beleive you understand the reason for adding ta.seat_available >0. DENSE_RANK will assign unique rank numbers for each stud_id based on the order_preferences. So when you put a filter condition on the dense_rank column ie., row_id = 1 only the first and third record will be returned from your tblAcademy_selection table.

Comment: Ah okay ,now that I have obtain the result ,I need to assign the academy to the student by updating by the acad_id column found in tblStudent for each stud_id respectively. I am having difficulty to do it, can you please help for that?

Comment: Since you are looping for each student, declare a variable and assign the acad_Id returned by your query to that variable. Then use normal update statement to update value like update tblStudent SET acad_Id = variable where stud_id = your array value. If this is helpful or answers your question, mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Does the storing of the values should be like this : String acad_Id = dt2.Rows[a2]["acad_Id"].ToString();
 array2[a2] = dt2.Rows[a2]["stud_id"].ToString();  and statement  will be "update tblStudent set acad_id='" + acad_Id + "' where stud_Id='" + array2[a2] + "'"  to I get it correct?